# PHP AJAX XML Live Search with minimum characters

Tags: php, ajax, xml

My problem relates to the Ajax PHP Live search that you can find on W3Schools. I'd like to only have results longer than 2 characters, but I can't seem to figure out where to change it... been researching for a while too, but didn't find anything about this specific code relating to minimum characters...

I've tried changing the str.length==0 to 1 and/or if (strlen($q)>0) to 1, which at first works and gives results after at least 2 characters have been typed, but when using backspace to 0 characters in the search field it returns an error that variable "hint is undefined"

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
<script>
function showResult(str) {
if (str.length==0) {
document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {  // code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
  document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=this.responseText;
  document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","livesearch.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

And the php:

```
<?php
$xmlDoc=new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("links.xml");

$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('link');

//get the q parameter from URL
$q=$_GET["q"];

//lookup all links from the xml file if length of q>0
if (strlen($q)>0) {
  $hint="";
  for($i=0; $i<($x->length); $i++) {
    $y=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title');
    $z=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('url');
    if ($y->item(0)->nodeType==1) {
      //find a link matching the search text
      if (stristr($y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q)) {
        if ($hint=="") {
          $hint="<a href='" .
          $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue .
          "' target='_blank'>" .
          $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        } else {
          $hint=$hint . "<br /><a href='" .
          $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue .
          "' target='_blank'>" .
          $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// Set output to "no suggestion" if no hint was found
// or to the correct values
if ($hint=="") {
  $response="no suggestion";
} else {
  $response=$hint;
}

//output the response
echo $response;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> when using backspace to 0 characters in the search field it returns an error that variable "hint is undefined"

Since variable hint is declared within if-else blocks.

```
if (strlen($q)>0) {
  $hint="";
```

Move the variable outside:

```
$hint="";
if (strlen($q)>0) {
```

Comment: fantastic, what I changed was (str.length==1) in the script and  $hint="";
if (strlen($q)>1) in the php. seems to work fine! :) thanks a lot!